# How can I set a segue to a different view controller from a table view controller, based on the detail text label of the table view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am just beginning to learn objective-c and programming in general, and I am really stuck on this issue. I am using storyboards to create an app that keeps scores for different types of games. I have a master view controller that is a table view and it has prototype cells with detail labels. There is an `AddKeeperViewController` that allows the user to input player names and the game type. The game type is then used as the detail label for the prototype cells.

I want to then have each cell push to a different view controller, depending on what the detail text label is. I only have 2 game types at the moment, I know I need to set up logic in tableView `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` that will choose which segue to take. I set up my segues from the view controller, not the cells, and they each have a unique identifier. I just don't know how to set up my if statements to use the `gameType` as the deciding factor for which segue to take.

Here is some of my code from my `MasterViewController.m` file:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"scoreKeeperCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    scoreKeeper *keeperAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [[cell textLabel]setText:keeperAtIndex.name];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:keeperAtIndex.gameType];

    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if(cell.detailTextLabel) {
          //statement
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowKeeperDetails"]) {
        MADDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        detailViewController.keeper = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're on the right track. However, I think you're waiting a bit too long to choose which segue to take. Perhaps something like this would work for you:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell.detailTextLabel.text isEqualToString:@"TEXT"]) 
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueTypeOne" sender:nil];
    } 
    else 
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueTypeTwo" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this! I cant tell if it will work or not because at the moment the segues aren't working at all. Do you know if I still need to have the prepareForSegue method? I tried leave it as it was before but with an else statement for the second segue as well and that didn't work.

Comment: Never mind, yes what you suggested worked! I was just having trouble because of a typo I didn't notice on didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Thank you thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You may also create different cell's prototypes, each one connected with a different segue leading to different views, and then use the right prototype to obtain cells in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.